# create array based on if condition using php

Tags: php

In Php
i want to create an array `$subject` using if statement like

i already have an array which may be have data or not named `$remark`

here is what i want

```
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","anderpoye","ex_smartcard2013");

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  { 
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$result3 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT  name,remark FROM sec_users where sec_users.email = 'shivesh@lotus.edu.in'");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result3))
{ 
if($row['remark'])
{ 
$remark= $row['remark'];

if $remark = null then $subject = "action Required"
else $subject = "";
echo $subject;
}
}
```

Means if $remark is empty then $subject = "action required" otherwise if $remark contains some data then $subject = "" means empty

Comment: This is quite illogical code. You check if connect() failed but if it did, you still try to use DB like nothing wrong happened?

Comment: Declare subject as an array 'subject[]' and populate it with data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not very clear but is this what you mean?

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result3)){
    if($row['remark']==null){
        $subject = 'Action Required';
    }else{
        $subject = '';
    }
    $remark = $row['remark'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in php you can add elements to an array using `[]`
here is an example

```
$set = array()
for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    $set[] = $i;
}
print_r($set);

// you can also set the key name in this way
for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    $set["ind_".$i] = $i;
}
print_r($set);
```

hope you got the idea